# vscode extension: How to realize the autocomplete feature?

Tags: visual-studio-code, autocomplete

I want to implement the code prompt function as shown below. like placeholder, when your use the keyboard to enter content，give some code hints。You can press the ‘tab’ key to accept the content。

I tried to do it with the "registerCodeLensProvider" method, but it only inserts small words above the code
And  then,I tried to do it with "createTextEditorDecorationType" method, but it only inserts some style above code without text。

How to realize the autocomplete feature as shown below?
Please suggest.

[image]

Comment: which `autocomplete`, is this a VSC screen shot? If so choose a different theme and implement your `CodeLensProvider`

Comment: like placeholder,  when your use the keyboard to enter content，give some code hints。You can press the ‘tab’ key to accept the content。

Comment: `CompletionItemProvider`

Comment: `CompletionItemProvider ` is poplayer  , I want to insert content to code  .The font is gray, and  no line numbers

Comment: what is `poplayer`, you don't mark the feature you want in the image, and the image is most likely not VSC

Comment: poplayer=》Down frame.
‘github coplite’ implements the effect。